# How to parse non blocking ServletInputStream?

Tags: java, parsing, jakarta-ee, servlets, asyncfileupload

I want to **asynchronously** and **non blocking** upload a file and read this article: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HTML5andServlet31/HTML5andServlet%203.1.html.

As well as in a java-ee book of mine, the proposed solution is something like this:

```
public class FotoReadListener implements ReadListener {

    private AsyncContext ac;
    private ServletInputStream is;
    private StringBuilder input;

    public FotoReadListener(final AsyncContext ac, final ServletInputStream is) {
        this.ac = ac;
        this.is = is;
        this.input = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataAvailable() throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();;
        while (is.isReady() && (len = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            String data = new String(b, 0, len);
            sb.append(data);
        }
        input.append(sb);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAllDataRead() throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw  = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\temp\\onAllDataRead.txt"));
        fw.write(input.toString());
        fw.close();
        ac.getResponse().getOutputStream().print("true");
        ac.complete();
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the `ServletInputStream` does have more than just the file:

```
-----------------------------7df230460a08
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

asdfasdf asdf asdf 
-----------------------------7df230460a08
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adfaf qwe asd fadklfj asdlkfh asdjfklasdhfjklasdf asdlkfh lasdjhflasdhlf hdlf halsdf asdf asdf asdf asdf df asd
-----------------------------7df230460a08
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

33
-----------------------------7df230460a08
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto"; filename="C:\temp\DSC_0675.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


-----------------------------7df230460a08--
```

How can I parse this input? Do I have to write my own parser for this - I would really wonder, if there is no better way to do that yet.

Comment: The input stream isn't non-blocking. You're confusing 'non-blocking' with 'asynchronous`. The `ReadListener` offers various guarantees about when its methods are invoked. It doesn't magically cause an `InputStream` to become non-blocking.